# Message from webpage. Stack overflow at line: 1

Tags: vba, error-handling, excel-2010, xmlhttprequest

This is the code and I get the above msg when I run it and F8 on the line described below.  Have to click the OK button 17 times before I can get out of it.  Happens for a few web pages only, the rest (1000s) work fine.  Tried `On Error Resume Next` before and after the line with no effect.  Any idea how the code can ignore the msg and proceed?

```
    Dim XMLHTTP As Object
    Dim myURL As String
    Dim html As Object

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", myURL, False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
    On Error Resume Next
    .send

    Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    html.body.innerHTML = .ResponseText 'getting the err msg here when I F8 on this line
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
On Error Resume Err_Label
Dim XMLHTTP As Object
Dim myURL As String
Dim html As Object

With CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
.Open "GET", myURL, False
.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"

.send

Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
html.body.innerHTML = .ResponseText 'getting the err msg here when I F8 on this line
End With

Exit sub

err_label:
'any error logging/reporting goes here
 exit sub
```

Comment: Yes, if there is an error you go to the err_label and then exit, and if the code progresses normally you exit before hitting err_label. If the code is in a function then it is exit function instead of exit sub

Comment: I got incorrect syntax for `On Error Resume Err_Label`, so I used `On Error GoTo Err_Label`.  I got the same err msg at the same line again and had to hit OK 17 times to get out of it.  Not sure if or what I need to do at `'any error logging/reporting goes here`...

Comment: You said - if the code progresses normally you exit before hitting err_label. Unless I don't have an option, I don't want to exit sub before hitting Err_Label, I would like to continue until I get to end sub.  Also does Err_label needs to be declared as something?

Comment: ok, figured out how your solution works :).  Although I still have to hit OK 17 times to get out of the msg box to `Err_Label`, the nice thing is, I can at least report there, which row the err is occurring at.  And if I comment out `exit sub` there, I can continue the progress of the code.  So getting back to my question - there isn't a way to automate the code to handle this error and then resume - w/o needing my manual intervention?